# Is it correct to use "how's" as short for "how does"?

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

I've often seen "how's" used as short for how is - such as "How's your wife feeling?" or "How's the weather where you are?"

I'm pretty sure the above is grammatically correct. However, it's also common to use "how's" as short for "how does", such as "How's it feel to be a student?"

Is this second usage grammatically correct, or just a colloquialism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be making the false assumption that colloquialisms are not grammatically correct. Contractions are a natural part of spoken language in any language in the world—it’s part of the very fundament of speaking that we contract things that provide little necessary information. That does not make them ungrammatical in any way; quite the opposite, in fact.

A better question to ask would be when and where it is *appropriate* to contract ‘how does’ to ‘how’s’.

As you yourself say, it is exceedingly common to do so in normal, informal, spoken language, and I would say there is no reason whatsoever *not* to do it in a colloquial situation, apart from wishing to add a particular feel, effect, emphasis, etc. to what you’re saying. In other words, it is quite on par with contracting ‘how is’ into ‘how’s’.

The more formal you get, the more likely it will become that ‘how’s’ (whether for ‘how does’ or ‘how is’) will be seen as unduly informal and not appropriate to the situation. And in writing that’s not meant to reproduce spoken language specifically, I would avoid it entirely.

Comment: I agree the broad thrust of all this, but I don't think *"How's it feel?"* is quite on a par with *"How's your bad leg?"*. It's a somewhat more extreme contraction, which arguably implies it's "more colloquial". And even where **'s = is**, as in the previous sentence, there can be differences. I'm inclined to think that in, say, *"If the Queen's coming to visit it's important to make sure your toilet is clean"* the first contraction is more informal than the second. And whilst I can't say it's *always* the case, I think ***can't*** is often "less informal" than many other contractions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm aware that it's appropriate in some cases and not others, but I was just wondering whether, strictly speaking adhering to the rules of English grammar, it's a correct use of an apostrophe or not?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Make sure you're not hearing a class/register difference between _How's it feel?_ and _How's your bad leg?_. They are both totally normal in the US, and our students are equally confused about them. The fact is that deleting material erases distinctions marked with it, so there is a gread deal of neutralization, like _he'd_ meaning _he did_ or _he would_, and we seem to take it in stride in speech. It's only in writing that the apostropocalypse threatens.

Comment: @John: I'm pretty sure I know what you're getting at there, since I think *deleting material erases distinctions marked with it* explains why I'm tempted to "reconstruct" *"If I'd have known you were coming I'd have baked a cake"* as *"If I **had** have known..."*. Which doubtless you find as ridiculous as *"How **is** it feel?"* sounds to me. But even though my "logical" brain can see what's going on, I can't easily retrain my "inner parser" to reconstruct the full form in my example.

Comment: Yup. Contractions can get fixed just like phrases. That's what's happened to imperfect construction _used to_ /yustə/. It works fine in the negative in speech as /'dɪdṇyustə/, but none of the available spellings work: _didn't used to_ looks wrong, and so does _didn't use to_. The inner reader doesn't like either one, though the inner speaker has no problem.

Comment: @John: I must remember that one! I've had fun discovering that I'm far from alone in my misparsing of *"If I'd have known"*, but I can imagine the written version of /'dɪdṇyustə/ will flummox even more people. I get the impression from OED that "technically speaking" it should be *didn't **use** to*, but my inner reader/grammarian/parser hasn't got a clue!

Comment: And I expect this is how the traditional phrase *"I had rather <verb>"* turned into the modern one *"I would rather <verb>"*. They're both contracted to *"I'd rather <verb>"* in speech. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+had+rather%2CI+would+rather&year_start=1575&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20had%20rather%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20would%20rather%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I think anybody saying that something is "technically speaking, (in)correct" should be required to state the technical details of the regulation involved, and why they apply to this particular item. Anyone citing a zombie rule will have their brains eaten.